# Masking values in two rows simultaneously in a 2D array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data with 3 columns - x,y and z. I want to mask certain values of x and y that falls in a range. For example, if I have a data with the following values
[x   y   z]=([0 1 1],[1   1   5], [2   1   2],[3   1   7],[0   2   6],[1 2   7],[2   2   5],[3   2   5]).

I want to mask values in the following two range (i)x = (0 to 3) and y= 1 and (ii) x = (2,3) and y=2. The z values corresponding to the above mask also should be avoided in the output.I would like to use the concept of masking rows and columns from the numpy.ma module.

I want an output [(0,2,6),(1,2,7)].

Thank you.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Abin, see my updated answer below :)  And sorry for misspelling your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works ;) Here I used a list comprehension to build a new list. Inside the list comprehension you can use `if` to filter the results.

```
my_array = np.array([[0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 5],[2, 1, 2],[3, 1, 7],[0, 2, 6],[1, 2, 7],[2, 2, 5],[3, 2, 5]])
def condition1(point):
    if point[0] in range(4) and point[1] == 1:
        return False
    return True
def condition2(point):
    if point[0] in range(2,4) and point[1] == 2:
        return False
    return True
result = [point for point in my_array if condition1(point) and condition2(point)]
```

giving you this result:

```
[array([0, 2, 6]), array([1, 2, 7])]
```

With `result = np.vstack(result)` you get

```
array([[0, 2, 6],
       [1, 2, 7]])
```

---

### Update:

If you want to use numpy.ma you can do this

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
my_array = np.array([[0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 5],[2, 1, 2],[3, 1, 7],[0, 2, 6],[1, 2, 7],[2, 2, 5],[3, 2, 5]])
condition1 = (my_array[:, 0] >= 0) & (my_array[:, 0] <= 3) & (my_array[:, 1] == 1)
condition2 = (my_array[:, 0] >= 2) & (my_array[:, 0] <= 3) & (my_array[:, 1] == 2)
ma.masked_array(my_array, mask=np.tile((condition1 | condition2), [3, 1]).T)
```

giving you this result

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- --]
 [-- -- --]
 [-- -- --]
 [-- -- --]
 [0 2 6]
 [1 2 7]
 [-- -- --]
 [-- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Still, I like my first solution more ;)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
import numpy as np

# your array
r = np.array([[0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 5], [2, 1, 2],[3, 1, 7],
              [0, 2, 6],[1, 2, 7],[2, 2, 5],[3, 2, 5]])

# your limits
max_r = [5,5,5]
min_r = [1,1,1]

filtered_r = r[(np.prod(r>=min_r, 1)  * np.prod(r<=max_r, 1)) == True]

>>>filtered_r
>>>array([[1, 1, 5],
   [2, 1, 2],
   [2, 2, 5],
   [3, 2, 5]])
```

Comment: This is not the output I want.